# How to split following string in java using brace

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
{"smscresponse":{"calluid":"3333","to":"0000","event":"ABC"}}
```

I am using

`split("{")[1]` to get `"calluid":"3333","to":"0000","event":"ABC"`

But i am getting

```
Illegal repetition
{ error.
```

What i want is calluid .How i can get that one.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use a JSON parser, Jackson, GSON etc. Or split using escape the change the split to split("\\{")

Comment: actually need to split only

Comment: `{"smscresponse":{"calluid":"3333","to":"0000","event":"ABC"}}`  is not a valid String. How can you `split`?

Comment: actually my requirement is to use only regex

Comment: Customer requirement or college assignment requirement?

Comment: @Adam no my team lead said dont use JSON in service layer

Comment: When you're team-lead said that I'm pretty sure he/she didn't mean use JSON strings, and bodge a regex parser yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could escape the `{` character, something like...

```
String text = "{\"smscresponse\": 
                 {\"calluid\":\"3333\",\"to\":\"0000\",\"event\":\"ABC\"}}";
String[] split = text.split("\\{");
System.out.println(split.length);
System.out.println(split[2]);
```

Which outputs...

```
3
"calluid":"3333","to":"0000","event":"ABC"}}
```

To get "3333", you could do something like...

```
split = split[2].split(":|,"); // Split on : or ,
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

Which outputs

```
"3333"
```

Now, if you really wanted to be clever, you could try something like...

```
String[] split = text.split("\\{|:|,|\\}");
for (String part : split) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Which outputs

```
                // Note, this is an empty line
"smscresponse"
                // Note, this is an empty line
"calluid"
"3333"
"to"
"0000"
"event"
"ABC"
```

**Updated...**

A slightly better solution might be...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Which outputs

```
"smscresponse"
"calluid"
"3333"
"to"
"0000"
"event"
"ABC"
```

Comment: do i  need to put \ in the string ?

Comment: @PSR  otherwise it is not a valid java string.

Comment: @PSR I depends.  If you constituting the `String` yourself (like I did) then yes.  If you're reading the `String` from some source, then no...

Comment: But it is generating dynamically

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you please differentiate between them ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ It's a valid `String` based on context, ie if it was read from a file our input stream ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's completely deceiving compiler. You can't escape from JRE :P

Comment: @PSR If I were to add `System.out.println(text);`, it would output `{"smscresponse":{"calluid":"3333","to":"0000","event":"ABC"}}`, you only need to escape the quote characters if you need to build the String yourself ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok thank u i understand this.But after that when i am splitting  "calluid":"3333","to":"0000","event":"ABC"} using .split(":"") i am getting error

Comment: @MadProgrammer how i can get 3333

Comment: Probably by splitting it again on `:`

Answer (score 1):

Try to split using `input.split("[{]");`

```
String abc = "{\"smscresponse\":{\"calluid\":\"3333\",\"to\":\"0000\",\"event\":\"ABC\"}}";
String[] splittedValue = abc.split("[{]");
for(String value : splittedValue)
  System.out.println(""+value);
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, missed the closing `]`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "{\"smscresponse\":{\"calluid\":\"3333\",\"to\":\"0000\",\"event\":\"ABC\"}}";
System.out.println(s.split("\\{")[2].split("}")[0]);
```

Don't worry about "\". This will work for your dynamically generated data.

EDIT : This will get you "calluid"

```
System.out.println(s.split("\\{")[2].split("}")[0].split(",")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON object of the given string and parse the JSON object to fetch the value. Use the library [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonSimpleExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"smscresponse\":{\"calluid\":\"3333\",\"to\":\"0000\",\"event\":\"ABC\"}}");

            String calluid = (String) jsonObject.get("smscresponse").getString("calluid");
            System.out.println(calluid);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
}
```